# DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory parameters for Net.IBM.Data.Db2 for .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, .net, db2, ado.net, .net-7.0

Previously, for .NET Framework 4.8 I was able to use (something like) the following to register the IBM iSeries factory:

```
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries", "IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26");
```

I understand that to connect using .NET 7.0 I now need to use the Net.IBM.Data.Db2 drivers.

What would be the equivalent parameter values for `DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory()` for Net.IBM.Data.Db2?  I can't seem to find it online.

I have installed the Net.IBM.Data.Db2 NuGet package.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, with .NET Framework I didn't actually have to use DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory() because I could use DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses() and it would get all available factories.  This no longer works in .NET 7.0... you have to use .RegisterFactory() or put the equivalent/corresponding entry in app.config.

Comment: Consider creating a question on the IBM community forum for data management, which might reach the Net.IBM.Data.Db2 devs  , at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datamanagement/communities/community-home/digestviewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can actually use this call instead:

```
using IBM.Data.Db2;
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("Net.IBM.Data.DB2", DB2Factory.Instance);
```

Note that if I then use:

```
DataTable dt = DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();
```

the data table will show the correct parameter value I was looking for:

```
"IBM.Data.Db2.DB2Factory, IBM.Data.Db2, Version=7.0.0.200, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208"
```